# qt ros tutorial issue

Tags: c++, ros

I am working on a robotic application under R.O.S. groovy Galapagos.
I would like to make a tutorial about how create a template app with catkin_create_qt_pkg.
I'm unable to call the script `catkin_create_qt_pkg` from my catkin workspace.
I found it at the root : _/opt/ros/groovy/qt_ros/qt_create/script_
But even if I try to execute it as sudoer I got an error.

> ImportError: No module named qt_create

I'm unable to determine what I have to do to make it work.

Why?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You will get better help for this question by asking on http://answers.ros.org, which is a similar, but more specific forum.

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry for being so late.

My OS is Linux Ubuntu 13.04.

I already fix that issue.
It was weird I just reuse an ROS exemple, readapt it exactly as I did when post that message, and everything worked ...

Thank you for your help

Jonny